# Host an NodeJS app

Tags: node.js, hosting, express

I created my personnal website with NodeJS in local, it works perfectly. But now, I'd like to host my app on a host. I tried to host on AppFog but it doesn't work, sessions doesn't really work, they sometimes destroy, I don't know where is the issue because they works great in local (the sessions)...

Furthermore, I get an error with the JSDOM module, it doesn't work on AppFog but it works on my local installation of NodeJS (v0.8.15).

The error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'implementation' of undefined
at exports.env.exports.jsdom.env.processHTML (/mnt/var/vcap.local/dea/apps/anthonycluse-1-  0c3b7373ee2a0a1334d2ea77a9bf22c8/app/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom.js:178:59)
at Object.exports.env.exports.jsdom.env (/mnt/var/vcap.local/dea/apps/anthonycluse-1-   0c3b7373ee2a0a1334d2ea77a9bf22c8/app/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom.js:269:5)
at exports.index.Creation.findAll.success.Post.findAll.success.async.map.res.render.creations (/mnt/var/vcap.local/dea/apps/anthonycluse-1- 0c3b7373ee2a0a1334d2ea77a9bf22c8/app/routes/index.js:50:23)
at _asyncMap (/mnt/var/vcap.local/dea/apps/anthonycluse-1-0c3b7373ee2a0a1334d2ea77a9bf22c8/app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:222:13)
at async.each (/mnt/var/vcap.local/dea/apps/anthonycluse-1-0c3b7373ee2a0a1334d2ea77a9bf22c8/app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:99:13)
at Array.forEach (native)
at _each (/mnt/var/vcap.local/dea/apps/anthonycluse-1-0c3b7373ee2a0a1334d2ea77a9bf22c8/app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:32:24)
at async.each (/mnt/var/vcap.local/dea/apps/anthonycluse-1-0c3b7373ee2a0a1334d2ea77a9bf22c8/app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:98:9)
at _asyncMap (/mnt/var/vcap.local/dea/apps/anthonycluse-1-0c3b7373ee2a0a1334d2ea77a9bf22c8/app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:221:9)
at Object.doParallel [as map] (/mnt/var/vcap.local/dea/apps/anthonycluse-1- 0c3b7373ee2a0a1334d2ea77a9bf22c8/app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:199:23)
```

Where can I host my NodeJS website without issue?

Anthony

Comment: Something like [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/)? `It provides you with complete control of your computing resources and lets you run on Amazon’s proven computing environment.` They also support [noSQL databases](https://aws.amazon.com/nosql/)

Comment: I use MySQL database with Sequelize.

Comment: That is possible also. In Amazon EC2 you have full control of your server, so if you want to install for example apache or php you are able to.

Comment: Ok and it's free? Do you think I will be no errors with Sessions and JSDOM module?

Comment: No Amazon is not free. Yes you can install everything, its your server(part) Sorry, I didn't read you want a free service to host your node app..

Comment: Give nodejitsu a go, they also provide application support. Also check out the node.js faq: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js?sort=faq&pagesize=30

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I host a Node.js app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648993/where-can-i-host-a-node-js-app)

Answer (score 2):

Many people use [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/) for this.

Comment: Can I use Heroku for MySQL databases?

Comment: I'm not the one that posted the answer, but I'm here so I'll answer you. You can easily connect to any MySQL database you have, but if you're looking for something through Heroku they have add-ons for MySQL (ClearDB) as well as Postgresql. There is also an add-on available to connect to an AWS RDS instance.

Comment: On AppFog I can create a new database (service), can I do it with Heroku? Because I saw ClearDB but, it seems it's only when we already have a database and when the project is in Ruby On Rails...

Answer (score 0):

I am hosting my nodejs with GigaPros.com [node.js hosting](http://www.gigapros.com/portal/nodejs-hosting). It have been a smooth sailing so far. You just get a ready-to-use nodejs env and simply deply your node.js app on it. It's a different concept; give it a try.